# Add multiple pages to pdf form with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream

I am trying to fill out a pdf form and the form could have multiple pages of the same form, so instead of writing each one to disk I want to create one pdf document in memory with all the pages.

I have seen plenty of example on adding pages from an existing pdf file with `FileStream` but nothing really for filling out forums and adding it to `MemoryStream`.

basically I need to fill out the forum with `PdfStamper` then append that form to a "master" `MemoryStream` because I dont want to write it to file.

this is basically what I have so far

```
List<Person> people = arson.getPeople();
MemoryStream main = new MemoryStream();
foreach (Person person in people )
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pathToPdf);
    MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, mem);

    //fill in forum with data from person then append

}
```

filling out the form is not the problem its just appending a new page to the `main` stream so that they are all in the same document. How can I add multiple pages in memory a not write it to disk first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you watch the iText video tutorial? You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c) and there's an example that is doing **exactly** what you're asking for.

If you don't like watching videos, you can also consult [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). There too you will find an example that explains what to do.

If you have a preference for a "recipe book" style, please take a look at [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). It has at least one example involving a combination of `PdfStamper` and `MemoryStream`.

If you did read the documentation, you would have found the example [DataSheets2](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/DataSheets2.cs):

```
// step 1
using (Document document = new Document()) {
    // step 2
    using (PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, ms)) {
        // step 3
        document.Open();
        // step 4
        AddDataSheets(copy);
    }
 }
```

You can find out what step 4 is about in [DataSheets1](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/DataSheets1.cs) to find out what step 4 is about:

```
public void AddDataSheets(PdfCopy copy) {
    IEnumerable<Movie> movies = PojoFactory.GetMovies();
    // Loop over all the movies and fill out the data sheet
    foreach (Movie movie in movies) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(DATASHEET_PATH);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
            Fill(stamper.AcroFields, movie);
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        }
        reader = new PdfReader(ms.ToArray());
        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, 1));
    }
}
```

As you can see, `DATASHEET_PATH` is the path to the form that we are going to reuse over and over again. We use `PdfStamper` to fill out a form in memory. We create a new `PdfReader` instance with `ms.ToArray()` as parameter.

In this case, we only add page 1 to the new PDF. If there are more pages, you need to loop over the different pages.

You may want to compare the result generated by `DataSheets1` with the results generated with `DataSheets2`. You will notice that `DataSheets1` is an example on how *not* to do it.

You already know what the `FillDataSheet()` method is about. If not, please take a look at the [FillDataSheet](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/FillDataSheet.cs) example:

```
public static void Fill(AcroFields form, Movie movie) {
    form.SetField("title", movie.MovieTitle);
    form.SetField("director", GetDirectors(movie));
    form.SetField("year", movie.Year.ToString());
    form.SetField("duration", movie.Duration.ToString());
    form.SetField("category", movie.entry.category.Keyword);
    foreach (Screening screening in movie.entry.Screenings) {
        form.SetField(screening.Location.Replace('.', '_'), "Yes");
    }
}
```