# Iterate through database records in groups of five to fill AcroFields with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, sql, linq, itext

In my .NET application, I have a PDF form that holds five records per page. I need to add database records to each page in groups of five records per page, mapping each column to a particular field. For each new group, I would need to add a new page to the pdf similar to [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304428/add-multiple-pages-to-pdf-form-with-itextsharp)

I am unable to find any examples to iterate through a query result in a batch of five records each.

Comment: You might want to check out [MoreLinq's](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) `Batch` method.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494393/what-is-the-best-way-to-fetch-records-batch-wise-from-sql-server.  The unaccepted "Offset-Fetch" answer is the right one (if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later).  The accepted answer was good 10 years ago, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Since I don't have any experience with iTextSharp I'll write this in pseudo-c#.

There are two basic ways to handle this:

1. Iterate through all of the records and create a new page when record number is a multiple of 5.
2. Collect `pageSize` (5) records into an array and pass to your page generation code.

For the first option you just iterate through the records as you would any other enumeration, counting as you go and starting a fresh page whenever you need to.  It looks something like this:

```
public void WritePDF(string filename, IEnumerable<RecordType> records, int rowsPerPage = 5)
{
    using (var file = CreatePDFFile(filename))
    {
        bool inPage = false;
        int recordNumber = 0;
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            int recordOffset = recordNumber % rowsPerPage;
            if (recordOffset == 0)
            {
                if (inPage)
                    FinishPage(file);
                StartPage(file);
                inPage = true;
            }
            WriteRecord(record, recordOffset);
            recordNumber++;
        }
        if (inPage)
            FinishPage(file);
    }
}
```

(Obviously you'll need to supply (or replace) the `CreatePDFFile`, `StartPage`, `FinishPage` and `WriteRecord` methods.)

The second option is to group up your records into blocks of 5 and send those groups to a `WritePage` method that creates the page and fills in the records.  Here's an extension (off the top of my head - might need some work) for doing the grouping:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TRecord[]> Batch<TRecord>(this IEnumerable<TRecord> seq, int batchSize)
    {
        T[] buffer = null;
        int offset = 0;
        foreach (var record in seq)
        {
            if (buffer == null)
            {
                buffer = new T[batchSize];
                offset = 0;
            }
            buffer[offset++] = record;
            if (offset == batchSize)
            {
                yield return buffer;
                buffer = null;
            }
        }
        if (buffer != null)
        {
            yield return buffer.Take(offset).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

From there your PDF generation might look something like this:

```
public void WritePDF(string filename, IEnumerable<RecordType> records, int rowsPerPage = 5)
{
    using (var file = CreatePDFFile(filename))
    {
        foreach (var batch in records.Batch(rowsPerPage))
            WritePDFPage(batch);
    }
}
```

Now your `WritePDFPage` will always receive an array of no more than `rowsPerPage` items to write.  The last call will have whatever records are left over and may be smaller than your batch size.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to incorporate this into my code and post the results here. I am relatively new at C# so it may take a while!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with SQL Server, you could use the ORDER BY clause using OFFSET-FETCH. OFFSET-FETCH enables you to return only a range of the rows selected by your query. However, it adds the functionality to supply a starting point (an offset) and a value to specify how many rows you would like to return (a fetch value). This provides a convenient technique for paging through results.